# Mongodb / MongoHQ connection from Nodejitsu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongohq, node-mongodb-native, nodejitsu

I seem to be having trouble connecting to MongoHQ (via MongoSkin) on jitsu.
I can connect from localhost though, and all I'm doing is changing my env
var and jitsu deploying. It's just strange that it works locally but not
deployed. I had talked with someone on IRC but unfortunately I didn't find
a solution.

I did notice this, the first error, which is mine as well:
http://errors.jit.su/

Is Mongoskin having any issues like this?

I have also tried using other modules (node-mongo-native, etc), and
with the same results- I can connect locally to MongoHQ, but not on jitsu.

Thanks for any help or insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@subdomain.mongohq.com:port/collectionName');
```

works flawlessly both locally and on jitsu, at least for me.

thats the string that nodejitsu gave me when creating the db in their webinterface.

i never tried any other mongo orm so i cant help with any other method of getting a connection to mongo.

have fun

jascha

edit: using the latest versions of all scripts here

(package.json: "mongoose": "latest" and so on)